# Why can't I satisfy the "Diamond Equipment" challenge in Age of Empires 2?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

I've tried to complete this challenge multiple times, but it never seems to complete. I have tried playing multiple single player skirmishes without cheats and completed all 15 blacksmith upgrades but have never been awarded this achievement.

I had no trouble completing the previous achievement, which was to kill some boars. But this one eludes me.

I have included an example game with settings as an example. I tried both with and without resources set to "infinite". I use "full tech tree" to ensure that no blacksmith upgrades are missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think full tech tree prevents your progress on the challenge. I'd just try with a civ with a full blacksmith and full tech tree disabled. Previous challenges also said that they could be earned in multiplayer or skirmish games, while this now only says "matches". If you earned the first challenge in multiplayer, it could be possible that all the challenges must be completed there (although I doubt that).

Comment: I don’t think you have to complete 15 upgrades in a single match (Just like you didn’t have to kill 10 boars in a single match), so you shouldn’t need to worry about which upgrades your civ has access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Despite there being 6 challenges, the ability to complete them has been staggered. They are "locked", I think for each one to be unlocked once a day. This was confusing because the "next challenge" unlock timer is only visible from the main menu and not the challenges list itself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that in your screenshot it does show as locked on that screen, though. In contrast to how it looks when it is available but not complete.